# Midjourney Discord image uploading problem

Tags: machine-learning, discord, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

Cannot use --version 4 with only a single image prompt.
Please add another image prompt, or a text prompt.
/imagine https://media.disc/

Try to upload image via link in midjourney discord faeing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. From the + button. Upload the image in (jpg, or png) format from your computer.
2. Once the image uploads in chat click on the image. And then copy the image address by right-clicking on the image.
3. Use the image link in your command: /imagine https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/997260995883966464 to create a 3d animate photo with wolf background red lighting.
4. Check discord chat for the result.

Comment: Thanks, Jabar i did all above steps after that also I'm received the same message

Answer (score 0):

Sloved
There is small changes in 3rd step :

1. Use the image link in your command: /imagine prompt https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/997260995883966464 to create a 3d animate photo with wolf background red lighting.o --v 4
2. add "--v 4" in last for version this will sloved the issues

Answer (score 0):

1. create your own server on discord
2. upload image in that server which you've created
3. right click on image and copy the Media link  i.e   (cdn link)
4. Now go to the Midjourney new comers channel and write your prompt

/imagine prompt: (paste link) and your prompt